# How can I change the affiliation style in aip-cp?

Tags: footnotes, titles, affiliation

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{The Big Bang theory}

\author[aff1]{J. Watson\corref{cor1}}
\eaddress{watson@gmail.com}
\author[aff2]{G. House}
\eaddress{house@gmail.disney}
\author[aff3]{H. Sherlock}
\eaddress{sherlock@gmail.disney}

\affil[aff1]{} 
\affil[aff2]{}
\affil[aff3]{Institute of Mathematical Sciences, \\
Faculty of Science, University of Wonderland,  Disneyland.}
\corresp[cor1]{Corresponding author: watson@gmail.com}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Suppose $G$ is a connected graph. 
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How can I make all the numbers (1, 2, 3) on the left, superscript institute address?  Note that all the authors are from the same institute.  This is the template for a conference.  Hopefully not change much in the command.

Comment: Hi! I know this isn't your first question, but still, welcome! It's better to use the 'code sample' markdown for the whole code, as I have done. You *can* do this by adding four spaces before each and every line but, obviously, you wouldn't really want to. Instead, highlight the whole code after you've pasted it in and click the code sample button (the one that looks like { }) - or use ctrl-k

Comment: Ok. Wait. I m trying.

Comment: Thank you. I will not make the same mistake again.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't worry about it. But you can easily see why it's better when the whole code is properly marked down, can't you? Much more user friendly. Sadly, its magic is limited, and I'm afraid I still don't know the answer. But, in general, it makes your question much easier and more attractive to work on :)

Comment: Welcome, again :) You'll notice that I edited-out the 'Thanks' part of your question. On this site (and most in the SE network), such salutatory and sign-off snippets are understood as implied. We do this so that we can focus on the content of the question (or answer) and present it well for future readers.

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly you want? I've read it a few times over, but I still don't really understand what you need just from reading the question. My gut instinct is to just give each author the `aff3` key (in this case) and remove `aff1` and `aff2`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [`aip-cp.cls`](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors) and working off the assumption that you want the blank institution lines to go away.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{The Big Bang theory}

\author[disneyland]{J. Watson\corref{cor1}}
\eaddress{watson@gmail.com}
\author[disneyland]{G. House}
\eaddress{house@gmail.disney}
\author[disneyland]{H. Sherlock}
\eaddress{sherlock@gmail.disney}

\affil[disneyland]{Institute of Mathematical Sciences, \\
Faculty of Science, University of Wonderland,  Disneyland.}
\corresp[cor1]{Corresponding author: watson@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Suppose $G$ is a connected graph. 
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```